# Microsoft Access String to Date type conversion

Tags: string, vba, date, ms-access

I am trying to create a database in MS Access in order keep SDS's in order. I am having problems getting a string to convert to a date, which would then be thrown into my access database. The date is in a form, and has input rules of `dd/mm/yyyy`, the same as the format of the date in Access, `dd/mm/yyyy`, any ideas?

Comment: "having problems" means what *exactly* ?  BTW making a blanket statement like "Not a fan of Microsoft products" is the best way to get no help.  Typically the people answering questions like this are likely to be, if not "fans", at least not averse to whatever you're asking about, so it's best not to be disparaging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to use `CDate(my_date)` which should convert every ms access valid format.

Comment: I tried CDate(), does CDate() require the input string to be in a certain format?

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't need anything but value - if you considered please check in Office - Support: https://support.office.com/client/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202